# Entity Framework Include returning different values for Single and Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My application can be used to send messages to a combination of single users and teams containing sets of users. The structure is such, that a `Message` entity has one `Recipients` entity, which in turn has a list of `User` entities and a list of `Team` entities.

I am trying to get a list of `Message` entities using EF Code First and Linq-to-Entities, and I want to Include the `Recipients` and `Teams` to avoid large amounts of lazy loading requests later on.

The strange thing is, the Teams list is always empty if I use the Include clause. After some experimenting, it boils down to this:

```
var messages = GetAll()
    .Include(m => m.Recipients.Teams)
    .Where(m => m.Id == 123)
    .ToList();
```

returns a list with one message, where the `Teams` list is empty. (`GetAll()` just returns an `IQueryable<Message>`.) But if I do

```
var message = GetAll()
    .Include(m => m.Recipients.Teams)
    .Single(m => m.Id == 123);
```

then I get the single message, with the `Teams` correctly populated.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Edit**: Here's the generated SQL (taken from Entity Framework Profiler)

**Where statement**

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id]             AS [Id],
               [Extent1].[ParentRelation] AS [ParentRelation],
               [Extent1].[CreatedUtc]     AS [CreatedUtc],
               [Extent1].[Subject]        AS [Subject],
               [Extent1].[Introduction]   AS [Introduction],
               [Extent1].[Body]           AS [Body],
               [Extent1].[GlobalId]       AS [GlobalId],
               [Extent1].[Team_Id]        AS [Team_Id],
               [Extent1].[Creator_Id]     AS [Creator_Id],
               [Extent1].[Parent_Id]      AS [Parent_Id],
               [Extent1].[ReplyTo_Id]     AS [ReplyTo_Id],
               [Join1].[Id1]              AS [Id1],
               [Join1].[ToSupervisors]    AS [ToSupervisors],
               [Join1].[Organisation_Id]  AS [Organisation_Id],
               [Join1].[Id2]              AS [Id2],
               [Join4].[Id3]              AS [Id3],
               [Join4].[Name]             AS [Name],
               [Join4].[CreatedUtc]       AS [CreatedUtc1],
               [Join4].[Description]      AS [Description],
               [Join4].[Color]            AS [Color],
               [Join4].[Status]           AS [Status],
               [Join4].[Organisation_Id]  AS [Organisation_Id1],
               CASE
                 WHEN ([Join4].[Recipients_Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int)
                 ELSE 1
               END                        AS [C1]
        FROM   [dbo].[Messages] AS [Extent1]
               INNER JOIN (SELECT [Extent2].[Id]              AS [Id1],
                                  [Extent2].[ToSupervisors]   AS [ToSupervisors],
                                  [Extent2].[Organisation_Id] AS [Organisation_Id],
                                  [Extent3].[Id]              AS [Id2]
                           FROM   [dbo].[Recipients] AS [Extent2]
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MessageExtensions] AS [Extent3]
                                    ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[Recipients_Id]) AS [Join1]
                 ON [Extent1].[Recipients_Id] = [Join1].[Id1]
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Extent4].[Recipients_Id]   AS [Recipients_Id1],
                                       [Extent5].[Id]              AS [Id3],
                                       [Extent5].[Name]            AS [Name],
                                       [Extent5].[CreatedUtc]      AS [CreatedUtc],
                                       [Extent5].[Description]     AS [Description],
                                       [Extent5].[Color]           AS [Color],
                                       [Extent5].[Status]          AS [Status],
                                       [Extent5].[Organisation_Id] AS [Organisation_Id],
                                       [Extent6].[Recipients_Id]   AS [Recipients_Id2]
                                FROM   [dbo].[RecipientsTeams] AS [Extent4]
                                       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Teams] AS [Extent5]
                                         ON [Extent4].[Team_Id] = [Extent5].[Id]
                                       INNER JOIN [dbo].[MessageExtensions] AS [Extent6]
                                         ON 1 = 1) AS [Join4]
                 ON ([Extent1].[Recipients_Id] = [Join4].[Recipients_Id2])
                    AND ([Extent1].[Recipients_Id] = [Join4].[Recipients_Id1])
        WHERE  11021 = [Extent1].[Id]) AS [Project1]
ORDER  BY [Project1].[Id] ASC,
          [Project1].[Id1] ASC,
          [Project1].[Id2] ASC,
          [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

**Single statement**

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT [Limit1].[Id1]             AS [Id],
               [Limit1].[ParentRelation]  AS [ParentRelation],
               [Limit1].[CreatedUtc]      AS [CreatedUtc],
               [Limit1].[Subject]         AS [Subject],
               [Limit1].[Introduction]    AS [Introduction],
               [Limit1].[Body1]           AS [Body],
               [Limit1].[GlobalId1]       AS [GlobalId],
               [Limit1].[Team_Id]         AS [Team_Id],
               [Limit1].[Creator_Id]      AS [Creator_Id],
               [Limit1].[Parent_Id]       AS [Parent_Id],
               [Limit1].[ReplyTo_Id]      AS [ReplyTo_Id],
               [Limit1].[Id2]             AS [Id1],
               [Limit1].[ToSupervisors]   AS [ToSupervisors],
               [Limit1].[Organisation_Id] AS [Organisation_Id],
               [Limit1].[Id3]             AS [Id2],
               [Join5].[Id4]              AS [Id3],
               [Join5].[Name]             AS [Name],
               [Join5].[CreatedUtc1]      AS [CreatedUtc1],
               [Join5].[Description]      AS [Description],
               [Join5].[Color]            AS [Color],
               [Join5].[Status]           AS [Status],
               [Join5].[Organisation_Id]  AS [Organisation_Id1],
               CASE
                 WHEN ([Join5].[Recipients_Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int)
                 ELSE 1
               END                        AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[Id]             AS [Id1],
                               [Extent1].[ParentRelation] AS [ParentRelation],
                               [Extent1].[CreatedUtc]     AS [CreatedUtc],
                               [Extent1].[Subject]        AS [Subject],
                               [Extent1].[Introduction]   AS [Introduction],
                               [Extent1].[Body]           AS [Body1],
                               [Extent1].[GlobalId]       AS [GlobalId1],
                               [Extent1].[Team_Id]        AS [Team_Id],
                               [Extent1].[Creator_Id]     AS [Creator_Id],
                               [Extent1].[Parent_Id]      AS [Parent_Id],
                               [Extent1].[ReplyTo_Id]     AS [ReplyTo_Id],
                               [Join1].[Id2],
                               [Join1].[ToSupervisors],
                               [Join1].[Organisation_Id],
                               [Join1].[Id3]
                FROM   [dbo].[Messages] AS [Extent1]
                       INNER JOIN (SELECT [Extent2].[Id]              AS [Id2],
                                          [Extent2].[ToSupervisors]   AS [ToSupervisors],
                                          [Extent2].[Organisation_Id] AS [Organisation_Id],
                                          [Extent3].[Id]              AS [Id3]
                                   FROM   [dbo].[Recipients] AS [Extent2]
                                          LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MessageExtensions] AS [Extent3]
                                            ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[Recipients_Id]) AS [Join1]
                         ON [Extent1].[Recipients_Id] = [Join1].[Id2]
                WHERE  11021 = [Extent1].[Id]) AS [Limit1]
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Extent4].[Recipients_Id]   AS [Recipients_Id1],
                                       [Extent5].[Id]              AS [Id4],
                                       [Extent5].[Name]            AS [Name],
                                       [Extent5].[CreatedUtc]      AS [CreatedUtc1],
                                       [Extent5].[Description]     AS [Description],
                                       [Extent5].[Color]           AS [Color],
                                       [Extent5].[Status]          AS [Status],
                                       [Extent5].[Organisation_Id] AS [Organisation_Id],
                                       [Join4].[Id5],
                                       [Join4].[Recipients_Id2]
                                FROM   [dbo].[RecipientsTeams] AS [Extent4]
                                       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Teams] AS [Extent5]
                                         ON [Extent4].[Team_Id] = [Extent5].[Id]
                                       INNER JOIN (SELECT [Extent6].[Id]            AS [Id5],
                                                          [Extent6].[Recipients_Id] AS [Recipients_Id2]
                                                   FROM   [dbo].[Messages] AS [Extent6]
                                                          LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MessageExtensions] AS [Extent7]
                                                            ON [Extent6].[Recipients_Id] = [Extent7].[Recipients_Id]) AS [Join4]
                                         ON [Extent4].[Recipients_Id] = [Join4].[Recipients_Id2]) AS [Join5]
                 ON [Limit1].[Id1] = [Join5].[Id5]) AS [Project1]
ORDER  BY [Project1].[Id] ASC,
          [Project1].[Id1] ASC,
          [Project1].[Id2] ASC,
          [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

When I run these queries by hand, I have the same result. For the `Where`, the `Team` related properties are all NULL, while for the `Single`, they are populated.

**Edit 2** The `GetAll` method is a repository method

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return Context.Set<T>();
}
```

where `T` is `Message`

Comment: It can't be. Did you look at sql code that goes to database?

Comment: What is the code in your GetAll() method?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Edited in SQL statements and GetAll method

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
var messages = GetAll().Include(m => m.Recipients.Teams)  .Where(m => m.Id == 123).Select(m=>m);

Comment: No change - the result is exactly the same.